# How can I properly setup basic traefik reverse proxy?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik, fastapi

Assume my current public IP is `101.15.14.71`, I have a domain called `example.com` which I configured using cloudflare and I created multiple DNS entry pointing to my public ip.

Eg:

```
1) new1.example.com - 101.15.14.71
2) new2.example.com - 101.15.14.71
3) new3.example.com - 101.15.14.71
```

Now, Here's my example project structure,

```
├── myapp
│   ├── app
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── Dockerfile
├── myapp1
│   ├── app
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── Dockerfile
└── traefik
    ├── acme.json
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── traefik_dynamic.toml
    └── traefik.toml
```

Here I have two fastAPIs (i.e., myapp, myapp1)

Here's the example code I have in **main.py** in both myapp and myapp1, Its exactly same but return staement is different that's all

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello world for my project myapp"}
```

Here's my **Dockerfile** for myapp and myapp1, here too both are exactly same but the only difference is I deploy myapp on `7777` and myapp1 on `7778` in different containers

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y -q build-essential python3-pip python3-dev

# python dependencies
RUN pip3 install -U pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip3 install gunicorn fastapi uvloop httptools "uvicorn[standard]"

# copy required files
RUN bash -c 'mkdir -p /app'
COPY ./app /app


ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/gunicorn \
    -b 0.0.0.0:7777 \ # this line I use for myapp dockerfile
    -b 0.0.0.0:7778 \ # this line I change for myapp1 dockerfile
    -w 1 \
    -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app \
    --chdir /app
```

Here's my **docker-compose.yml** file for myapp and myapp1, here also I have exactly same but only difference is I change the port,

> ```
> services:
>   myapp:  # I use this line for myapp docker-compose file
>   myapp1: # I use this line for myapp1 docker-compose file
>     build: .
>     restart: always
>     labels:
>       - "traefik.enable=true"
>       - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_public"
>
>       - "traefik.backend=myapp" # I use this line for myapp docker-compose file
>       - "traefik.backend=myapp1" # I use this line for myapp1 docker-compose file
>
>
>       - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:new2.example.com" # I use this for myapp compose file
>       - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:new3.example.com" # I use this for myapp1 compose file
>
>       - "traefik.port=7777" # I use this line for myapp docker-compose file
>       - "traefik.port=7778" # I use this line for myapp1 docker-compose file
>     networks:
>       - traefik_public
>
> networks:
>   traefik_public:
>     external: true
> ```

Now coming to traefik folder,

1. **acme.json** # I created it using `nano acme.json` command with nothing in it,
   but did `chmod 600 acme.json` for proper permissions.
2. traefik_dynamic.toml

> ```
> [http]
>   [http.routers]
>     [http.routers.route0]
>       entryPoints = ["web"]
>       middlewares = ["my-basic-auth"]
>       service = "api@internal"
>       rule = "Host(`new1.example.com`)"
>       [http.routers.route0.tls]
>         certResolver = "myresolver"
>
> [http.middlewares.test-auth.basicAuth]
>   users = [
>     ["admin:your_encrypted_password"]
>   ]
> ```

3. traefik.toml

> ```
> [entryPoints]
>   [entryPoints.web]
>     address = ":80"
>     [entryPoints.web.http]
>       [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
>         [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
>           to = "websecure"
>           scheme = "https"
>
>   [entryPoints.websecure]
>     address = ":443"
>
> [api]
>   dashboard = true
>
> [certificatesResolvers.myresolver.acme]
>   email = "reallygoodtraefik@gmail.com"
>   storage= "acme.json"
>   [certificatesResolvers.myresolver.acme.httpChallenge]
>     entryPoint = "web"
>
> [providers]
>   [providers.docker]
>     watch = true
>     network = "web"
>   [providers.file]
>     filename = "traefik_dynamic.toml"
> ```

4. docker-compose.yml

> ```
> services:
>   traefik:
>     image: traefik:latest
>     ports:
>       - 80:80
>       - 443:443
>       - 8080:8080
>     volumes:
>       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
>       - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
>       - ./acme.json:/acme.json
>       - ./traefik_dynamic.toml:/traefik_dynamic.toml
>     networks:
>       - web
>
> networks:
>   web:
> ```

These are the details about my files, what I am trying to achieve here is,

I want to setup traefik and traefik dashboard with basic authentication, and I deploy two of my fastapi services,

- myapp **7777**, I need to access this app via `new2.example.com`
- myapp1 **7778**, I need to access this app via `new3.example.com`
- traefik dashboard, I need to access this via `new1.example.com`

All of these should be https and also has certification autorenew enabled.

I got all these from online articles for latest version of traefik. But the problem is this is not working. I used docker-compose to build and deploy the traefik and I open the api dashboard. It is asking for password and user (`basic auth I setup`) I entered my user details I setup in `traefik_dynamic.toml` but its not working.

Where did I do wrong? Please help me correcting mistakes in my configuration. I am really interested to learn more about this.

Error Update:

```
traefik_1  | time="2021-06-16T01:51:16Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"new1.example.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [new1.example.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[new1.example.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from http://new1.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/mu85LkYEjlvnbDI-wM2xMaRFO1QsPDNjepTDb47dWF0 [2606:4700:3032::6815:55c4]: 404\n" rule="Host(`new1.example.com`)" routerName=api@docker providerName=myresolver.acme

traefik_1  | time="2021-06-16T01:51:19Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"new2.example.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [new2.example.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[new2.example.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from http://new2.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ykiCAEpJeQ1qgVdeFtSRo3q-ATTwgKdRdGHUs2kgIsY [2606:4700:3031::ac43:d1e9]: 404\n" providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=myapp1@docker rule="Host(`new2.example.com`)"

traefik_1  | time="2021-06-16T01:51:20Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"new3.example.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [new3.example.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[new3.example.com] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: Invalid response from http://new3.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/BUZWuWdNd2XAXwXCwkeqe5-PHb8cGV8V6UtzeLaKryE [2606:4700:3031::ac43:d1e9]: 404\n" providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=myapp@docker rule="Host(`new3.example.com`)"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need one docker-compose file for all the services, and there is no need to define one for each container.

The project structure you should be using should be something like:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── myapp
│   ├── .dockerignore
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── app
│       └── main.py
├── myapp1
│   ├── .dockerignore
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── app
│       └── main.py
└── traefik
    ├── acme.json
    └── traefik.yml
```

When creating containers, unless they are to be used for development purposes, it is recommended to not use a full-blown image, like ubuntu. Specifically for your purposes I would recommend a python image, such as `python:3.7-slim`.

Not sure if you are using this for development or production purposes, but you could also use volumes to mount the app directories inside the containers (especially useful if you are using this for development), and only use one Dockerfile for both `myapp` and `myapp1`, customizing it via environment variables.

Since you are already using traefik's dynamic configuration, I will do most of the setup for the container configuration via docker labels in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Your dockerfile for `myapp` and `myapp1` will be very similar at this point, but I've kept them as seperate ones, since you may need to make changes to them depending on the requirements of your apps in the future. I've used an environment variable for the port, which can allow you to change the port from your `docker-compose.yml` file.

You can use the following `Dockerfile` (`./myapp/Dockerfile` and `./myapp1/Dockerfile`):

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN pip3 install -U pip setuptools wheel && \
    pip3 install gunicorn fastapi uvloop httptools "uvicorn[standard]"

COPY . /app

ENV PORT=7777 # and 7778 for myapp1

ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app --chdir /app
```

Note: you should really be using something like [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) or a [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file for your app dependencies.

The `.dockerignore` file (`./myapp/.dockerignore` and `./myapp1/.dockerignore`) should contain:

```
Dockerfile
```

Since the whole directory is being copied inside the container and you don't need the `Dockerfile` to be in there.

Your main traefik config (`./traefik/traefik.yml`) can be something like:

```yml
providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false

global:
  checkNewVersion: false
  sendAnonymousUsage: false

api: {}
accessLog: {}

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: "websecure"
          scheme: "https"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

ping:
  entryPoint: "websecure"

certificatesResolvers:
  myresolver:
    acme:
      caServer: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      email: "example@example.com"
      storage: "/etc/traefik/acme.json"
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: "web"
```

Note: The above acme config will use the stage letsencrypt server. Make sure all the details are correct, and remove `caServer` after you've tested that everything works, in order to communicate with the letsencrypt production server.

Your `./docker-compose.yml` file should be something like:

```yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: ./myapp
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: myapp
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    expose:
      - 7777
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.tls.certResolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.rule=Host(`new2.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.server.port=7777"
  myapp1:
    build:
      context: ./myapp1
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: myapp1
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    expose:
      - 7778
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp1.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp1.tls.certResolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp1.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp1.rule=Host(`new3.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp1.loadbalancer.server.port=7778"
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - ./traefik/acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme.json
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certResolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`new1.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=myAuth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.myAuth.basicAuth.users=admin:$$apr1$$4zjvsq3w$$fLCqJddLvrIZA.CCoGE2E." # generate with htpasswd. replace $ with $$
```

You can generate the password by using the command:

```
htpasswd -n admin | sed 's/\$/\$\$/g'
```

Note: If you need a literal dollar sign in the docker-compose file you need to use `$$` as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution).

Issuing `docker-compose up` in the directory should bring all the services up, and working as expected.

The above should work for you based on the details you have provided, but can be further improved at multiple points, depending on your needs.

Moreover, having the credentials for the traefik dashboard in the `docker-compose.yml` file is probably not the best, and you may want to use docker secrets for it. You can also add healthchecks and consider placing `myapp` and `myapp1` into a seperate internal network.

If you want to get further into it, I propose that you start with [Get started with Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) and also read: [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out. I am receiving some error. I have updated the question with the error can you help with the error

Comment: I was getting that error only on my local when I tried this on aws ec2 instance its working fine. There is one issue in aws ec2 instance, when I try to go to `new1.example.com` and it asks for username and password. I entered it but it keeps asking me again. Its not authorizing my username and password. Can you tell me how to create username and password using htpasswd. And why is it that we need to replace `#` with two `##`?

Comment: Regarding your initial error, acme will only generate the certificate if it can reach the specific domain from the internet, so it would be normal not being able to do so, if the domain and service is not externally accessible. I will update the answer to include the password generation command